# Angular 4. click event handler not called in case of ngAfterViewChecked takes long time

Tags: angular

**Update** As this example not enough to reproduce issue I create new question [Angular 4. click event handler can be not called in case of document:touchstart handler call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286661/angular-4-click-event-handler-can-be-not-called-in-case-of-documenttouchstart)

I have a block with click event handler. In Component I have

- ngAfterViewChecked()
- onCollapse() //click event handler

methods. User click the block and I think the `onCollapse()` method should be called but this not happen if `ngAfterViewChecked()` take some long time to process. When I set breakpoint in `ngAfterViewChecked()` method, the `onCollapse()` click event handler not called. Why?

**Component**

```
@Component
export class MyClass implements AfterViewChecked{
    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        //breakpoint here
        console.log("ngAfterViewChecked");
    }

    onCollapse(index: number) {
        console.log("onCollapse");
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="collapse_section" *ngFor="let event of event_role; let i = index" #jobBody>
    <header accordion-heading (click)="onCollapse(i)" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed">
        ...
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Given your code, you should have no error. This means either you did something wrong, or you're not posting the whole code. If so, could you please post the whole code ? If you don't know your error, don't assume it is there, it could be anywhere

Comment: I will try to reproduce on small application then

Comment: Hi I was able to reproduce on small application. You was right this code not enough to catch the issue. I will create new question and left link here